# Livewire Component not found when hosted on hostinger

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I wanted to host a laravel project using Hostinger. The project contains livewire components in it. Every thing is working properly but when I open a page that contains livewire components it shows this error `Unable to find component: [masteradmin.park.park-edit]`. It works fine in local their is no issue in local.

I have tried all the previous solutions over stackoverflow but didn't found any solution. I have downloaded composer (latest version) and then installed liverwire too, but yet no luck.
I am using ssh to push in hostinger.